# Google maps API directions service redirects to JSON info, but how do I get it to open map app in phone?

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-urls

I'm new to Google Map API. The following javascript opens a new page with the JSON data. The google documentation gives the following URL example, (I added the window.open javascript part). But there isn't a complete example anywhere that I found.

I'm trying to open this from my asp.net website, into open the google maps app on a phone to the places indicated. Of course, the places will be put in programmically.

```
function myNavFunc4(){
window.open("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Chicago,IL&destination=Los+Angeles,CA&waypoints=Joplin,MO|Oklahoma+City,OK&key=My_KEY");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to launch Google Maps app from your website you can use the [Google Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started). This API was designed for this purpose.

Instead of using Directions API web service endpoint in your script you should create a Google Maps URL for directions.

E.g.

```
function myNavFunc4(){
    window.open("https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=Chicago,IL&destination=Los+Angeles,CA&waypoints=Joplin,MO|Oklahoma+City,OK");
}
```

For further details please have a look at Google Maps URLs documentation.

Enjoy.